# Idempotent elements of $Z_4 \times Z_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, idempotents

I am trying to find idempotent elements of the direct product $Z_4 \times Z_8$.
By the definition of direct product we have:
$$Z_4 \times Z_8=\left\{(0,0),(0,1),.....(2,7),(3,7)\right\}$$
Now by the definition of idempotent element we have:
$$(a,b)*(a,b)=(a,b)$$
$\implies$
$$(a^2,b^2)=(a,b)$$
$\implies$
$a=0,1$ and $b=0,1$
So the idempotent elements are
$$(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$$
Is this correct? Can we say every $Z_m \times Z_n$, these will be the only idempotent elements?

Comment: No, in $\mathbb Z_6$, we have $3^2=3$.

Comment: To add to @KentaS comment, no, not at all.

In general, we could say that for $\mathbb{Z}_n$ where $n = 2(2k+1)$, meaning that $n$ is even and $\frac{n}{2}$ is odd, you get $\frac{n}{2} \equiv \frac{n}{2}$ mod $n$ for all $n$ that satisfy the definition I just gave.  Example: Let $n =14$. Then $(7)^2$ mod $14 \equiv 49$ mod $14 \equiv 7$ mod $14$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you showed the idempotent elements of $\mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_8$ are those of the form $(e_1,e_2)$ where $e_1$ is an idempotent element of $\mathbb Z_4$ and $e_2$ is an idempotent element of $\mathbb Z_8$. (this part works for any product of rings $R\times S$).

I add a proof that the idempotent elements of $\mathbb Z_{p^k}$ are just $0$ and $1$:

Suppose $p^k|(a^2-a) = a(a-1)$. Because $a$ and $a-1$ are coprime $p$ can only divide $a$ or $a-1$ which means $p^k$ divides $a$ or $p^k$ divides $a-1$.

However if $n$ is not a prime power there are more idempotent elements of $\mathbb Z_n$. Let $n=ab$ with $a,b>1$ and $a$ and $b$ coprime. Take $x$ such that $x\equiv 0\bmod a$ and $x\equiv 1\bmod b$ to get an idempotent element that is not $0$ or $1$. It is not hard to show $\mathbb Z_n$ has $2^s$ idempotent elements, where $s$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.